# How do I create a binary feature vector for my classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I have successfuly implemented SVM classifier. I am not using the scikit approach. I am currently training it with different types of data. Now, I want to test it for a single text input. 
I tried using pandas but then I had to change my approach so I decided not to use it.
The classifier is being used for sentiment analysis with positive, negative and neutral labels. The data set which is fed to classifier is made up of tweets from twitter.
Here's my classifier: https://pastebin.com/JZ5LVLW7

So, I need help in designing a function in python that will take a string input, **compare it with my features list** and generate a binary vector. Or if there is other alternative, please do suggest.
Example: If my text input is "Football is a popular sport in Europe"
So, the proposed function would scan the feature list(already generated with the help of test data), and if the feature words like "football", "popular", "sport", "Europe" is present in the feature list it would append 1 or else 0. Hence, after the scanning through the function,the output should be like [..., 1,0,1,1,0,0,0,...].

Comment: What is the classifier for and what is the feature what is the target?

Comment: Sorry for skipping few details. The classifier is for sentiment analysis with positive, negative and neutral labels, it contains features that are extracted from datasets of tweets.

Comment: So you mean to generate one-hot feature for text input? scikit has some text feature tools for that.

Comment: hot-feature? Just a feature vector that scans the feature list and produces binary array of 1(if feature of input is present) or 0 otherwise. Please check the example.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html It is what you want?

Comment: yes, except my input is in text(string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a vocabulary with the words that you're interested and a hot encoder of the same size. Read the text file, and update the hot encoder in case you find the words in your vocabulary. This code should work.

```
vocabulary = ['Football', 'Europe'] # Put your targer words in here
hot_encoder = [0] * len(vocabulary)
binary_bag = dict(zip(vocabulary, hot_encoder))
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f: #Put your text sample in here
    words = [word for line in f for word in line.split()]
    for word in words:
        if word in vocabulary and binary_bag[word] == 0:
            binary_bag[word] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If only I could hide the labels in the output. Example: Instead of ['Football':1, 'Europe':0..] Could it be just [1,0,0..]?

Comment: Be careful in this step. Since you're working with a dictionary, you should remember that dicts don't maintain order. Therefore, you should use the initial lists to help you in achieving this goal. This code should work: `for idx, key in enumerate(vocabulary):
    hot_encoder[idx] = binary_bag[key]`